# Access chromeOS's internal api via chrome app

Tags: google-chrome-app, chromebook

I need to access chromeOs's internal api in a chrome-app I'm making. Is there a way to do this.

Comment: What is the internal API you want to use?

Comment: I want to use the same api that crosh uses

Answer (score 0):

Nothing. You can use [APIs for Chrome apps](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/api_index) only.